# cdata within cdata in XML

Tags: xml, special-characters, cdata

i want to use CDATA within CDATA in XML i tried following codes, but both are showing error.

**1.**

```
 <extraScript><![CDATA[

        <subScript><![CDATA[this.value]]></subScript>

 ]]></extraScript>
```

**2.**

```
 <extraScript><![CDATA[

        <subScript><![CDATA[this.value]]]]><![CDATA[></subScript>

 ]]></extraScript>
```

i refereed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860754/using-cdata-inside-another-cdata) in SO

according to that answer i tried second one but `</subScript>` is making problem how i can escape these part. some helps??

Answer (score 4):

You can't nest CDATA blocks.

The first `]]>` will terminate the *first* CDATA block and then the next end tag will not be well-formed.

Use character references (`&lt;` et al) instead.

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860754/using-cdata-inside-another-cdata) in SO

Comment: @chriz — That is another approach you could take, although it is not "escaping" anything, and still doesn't have nested CDATA blocks.

Comment: @chriz — Why do you want a third solution? You have two already.

Comment: <extraScript><![CDATA[

        <subScript><![CDATA[this.value]]]]><![CDATA[>&lt;/subScript>

 ]]></extraScript> did u mean like this and none of these solutions are working for me :(

Comment: No. I said **instead**. You should have only a single CDATA block.