# How to add literal CDATA tags to a sublime text snippet file?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

is there any way to add  tags to the content of a Sublime Text snippet? CDATA tags are used by Sublime Text to distinguish between the snippet XML and the actual snippet content.

I have not been able to get it to work except for

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<![CDATA[  ]${1:\\}]>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html.basic</scope>
</snippet>
```

Which requires that I manually delete the extra slash. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the snippet to output slashes, why do you put them there in the first place?

This works fine for my understanding, but only when there's an extra-space before the closing `>`.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<![CDATA[ $1 ]] >
]]></content>
    <scope>text.html.basic</scope>
</snippet>
```

It seems to be more related to the XML standard rather than being a specific issue with Sublime Text. Take a look at this question: [Using CDATA inside another CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860754/using-cdata-inside-another-cdata).

Comment: Well I did not know you could omit content with placeholder tokens. I would prefer to have the cursor inside the CDATA[ ] brackets, but I don't think that's possible. This will do just fine for now.

Comment: Just use `<![CDATA[ $1 ]]>` then

Comment: OK I'm not sure if it's apparent to you, but Sublime Text 3 uses <![CDATA[ ]]> to distinguish what is snippet content and what is XML. I already tried using <![CDATA[ $1 ]]>, but all that outputs is just  "]]>". This is what the snippet file would like:
    <snippet>
 <content><![CDATA[
<![CDATA[ $1 ]]>
]]></content></snippet>

Do you see the problem? The first CDATA is being closed prematurely by the presence of the CDATA tag that is supposed to be the snippet content.

Comment: It works with extra space, e.g. `<![CDATA[ $1 ]] >`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: A shame this doesn't work perfectly - the XML processor I'm using (I think its MSXML, doesn't parse the extra space properly; it needs to be ]]>. I'd have to keep removing the space every time I use the snippet. I'll just go with your first suggestion.