# xml request CDATA inside another CDATA how to scape

Tags: xml, request, escaping

I work with SOAPUI and I have a  request with a XML which have two CDATA, one inside another.
I tried to scape them but unsuccesfully. I read that I have to scape the CDATA but I don't understand how to do.

The request is

```
<DatosFirmados>
   <DatosRegistro>
      <DescripcionProcedimiento>Subvenciones destinadas a agrupaciones de productores para la realización de proyectos de investigación aplicada e innovación en el sector apícola - SUBDIRECCIÓN GENERAL DE PRODUCTOS GANADEROS</DescripcionProcedimiento>
      <CodigoProcedimiento>SEDE_322_81</CodigoProcedimiento>
      <Resumen>Subvenciones destinadas a agrupaciones de productores para la realización de proyectos de investigación aplicada e innovación en el sector apícola</Resumen>
      <Observaciones>SUBDIRECCIÓN GENERAL DE PRODUCTOS GANADEROS</Observaciones>
      <UTDestino>
         <CodigoUTDestino>50332631</CodigoUTDestino>
         <DescripcionUTDestino>REGISTRO GENERAL DEL M.A.R.M.</DescripcionUTDestino>
      </UTDestino>
      <Oficina>
         <CodigoOficina>63109999</CodigoOficina>
         <DescripcionOficina>REGISTRO TELEMATICO DEL MINISTERIO DE AGRICULTURA Y PESCA, ALIMENTACIÓN Y MEDIO AMBIENTE</DescripcionOficina>
      </Oficina>
      <FechaSolicitud>14-05-2018 15:15:51</FechaSolicitud>
      <Interesados>
         <Interesado>
            <IntTipo>J</IntTipo>
            <IntTxtDoc>Q0100000I</IntTxtDoc>
            <IntTxtId>FUFASA</IntTxtId>
            <IntNombre>FUFASA</IntNombre>
            <IntApellido1 />
            <IntApellido2 />
            <IntTipoCon>CE</IntTipoCon>
            <IntTxtCon>at_desarrollo3@mapama.es</IntTxtCon>
            <IntFormNoti>Formato electrónico</IntFormNoti>
         </Interesado>
      </Interesados>
   </DatosRegistro>
   <DatosProcedimiento>
      <Remitente>
         <RemNombre>FUFASA</RemNombre>
         <RemDoc>Q0100000I</RemDoc>
      </Remitente>
      <Solicitante>
         <SolCanal>Correo electrónico</SolCanal>
         <SolCodTipoSol>R</SolCodTipoSol>
         <SolPresentaSol>Certificado digital de representante</SolPresentaSol>
         <SolDireccion>C/ Las Aguilas s/n</SolDireccion>
         <SolCodPostal>28005</SolCodPostal>
         <SolMunicipio>Madrid</SolMunicipio>
         <SolProvincia>Madrid</SolProvincia>
         <SolPais>España</SolPais>
         <SolTel>914523654</SolTel>
         <SolCorreoElectronico>at_desarrollo3@mapama.es</SolCorreoElectronico>
         <SolNombreRepresentante>MANUELA BLANCO VIDAL</SolNombreRepresentante>
         <SolDniRepresentante>10000322Z</SolDniRepresentante>
      </Solicitante>
   </DatosProcedimiento>
   <DatosFormulario><![CDATA[<Documentacion><MemoriaCientifica>true</MemoriaCientifica><MemoriaEconomica>true</MemoriaEconomica><AyudasOtros>true</AyudasOtros><AyudasMismo>true</AyudasMismo><ImporteSubvencionable>true</ImporteSubvencionable><AcreditacionRep>true</AcreditacionRep><Otros>false</Otros><OtrosDetalle /><Curriculum>true</Curriculum><CorrientePago>true</CorrientePago><DocContractual>true</DocContractual><DocFormalizacion>true</DocFormalizacion><Poder>true</Poder><DeclaracionCifra>true</DeclaracionCifra><DeclaracionCrisis>true</DeclaracionCrisis></Documentacion><PropuestaFinanciera><Ejercicio><IdEvaluacion>1</IdEvaluacion><PersonalInvestigador>12000.0</PersonalInvestigador><PersonalContratado>1000.0</PersonalContratado><PersonalEventual>1000.0</PersonalEventual><EquipCientifico>5000.0</EquipCientifico><InvestContractual>2400.0</InvestContractual><MaterialFungible>1000.0</MaterialFungible><ViajesDietas>2000.0</ViajesDietas><OtrosGastos>1000.0</OtrosGastos></Ejercicio></PropuestaFinanciera><Titulo>Titulo pruebas correo</Titulo><Finalidad>Finalidad enviar correo</Finalidad><AutorizacionSolicitante>false</AutorizacionSolicitante><AutorizacionOrgano>false</AutorizacionOrgano><Regas><Rega>ES280790000002</Rega></Regas>]]></DatosFormulario>
</DatosFirmados>
```

How do I have to escape these CDATA?

Comment: you should probably edit your example to show the CDATA you want to put inside of the other CDATA and then the error you are getting that prevents you doing this. However I believe this is also a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860754/using-cdata-inside-another-cdata

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CDATA inside another CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860754/using-cdata-inside-another-cdata)

Comment: actually I tried to retract my flag as I could improve it as the better answer would be this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml but then it didn't let me reflag it. So if someone else wants to reflag would be good.